# login with app what I have to pay attention to?

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

In Webapps you create your login example with sessions and cookies. But in a App that doesnt exists. So if I store the user_id after login in the SecureStore on the device, is that enough ?
or do I have to pay attention to something ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is likely too broad to answer precisely, but it looks like you are basically asking what do you have to pay attention to when authenticating in Expo or React-Native.

My best suggestion is you start by reading this in its entirety:  ​https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/

For example, in my particular app, I use an OAuth provider and AuthSession to authenticate in my app and it returns a token back and its the token that I attach to all requests sent to the server via a "bearer" token header. A secret key is shared by the Authentication Server and my back-end which can validate the token isn't bogus.

It's best to work with an authentication scheme where you can verify users identity on the back-end precisely, so tokens (look up JWTs specifically) are useful for that. Storing just the user_id isn't really unique (anyone can send that).